# Diagonalization over rings and the dimension of the cokernel of an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

So, I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a DVR, $M$ a finite-rank free $\mathcal{O}$-module, and $\varphi \colon M \to M$. Then $\dim_k (M/\varphi(M)) < \infty \Leftrightarrow v_\mathcal{O}(\det \varphi) \neq 0$ and in the case where the cokernel is of finite dimension, we
>   have that $\dim_k (M/\varphi(M)) = v_\mathcal{O}(\det \varphi)$.

Here $k$ is meant to be some algebraically closed field and $\mathcal{O}$ a ring of polynomial functions over it. Let's assume for a moment that $\varphi$ is diagonalizable, or really that it's diagonal. Then decompose it into 1x1 blocks $a_i$. We have $\dim_k (M/\varphi(M)) = \sum \dim_k \text{Coker}(a_i)$. But the $a_i$ act on an ordered basis hence individually they act on $\mathcal{O}$ and we have $a_i \colon \mathcal{O} \to \pi^{n_i} \mathcal{O}$, where $n_i = v_\mathcal{O}(a_i)$. Because the determinant of $\varphi$ is the product of the $a_i$, the desired equality follows almost immediately.

What happens in the non-diagonal case? Jordan Normal Form does not exist over just any ring (although, for what it's worth, we can assume that $\mathcal{O}$ is a collection of rational functions), and even something like it did the blocks would be much more difficult to work with. Any hints?

Comment: I apologize, and that probably completely changed the interpretation of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may assume that $\phi$ is diagonal using the Smith Normal Form (which works since $\mathcal{O}$ is a PID). I assume instead of $\dim$ you use $\mathrm{length}_{\mathcal{O}}$.

Comment: As I noted in an above comment, I meant to write $\dim_k$ instead of $\dim$. However Smith Normal Form is magic, thanks for the introduction.

Comment: Also, I do not see how Smith Normal Form helps. The diagonal entries do not have to be the eigenvalues, or even multiply to the determinant.

Comment: Why don't they multiply to the determinant?

Comment: I'm not sure why they would. The diagonalizing matrices aren't inverses of each other, they're just invertible. For instance, you could just multiply everything in the Smith matrix by one half and everything in the first diagonalizing matrix by 2 to get the same result.