# The order of the cokernel of an endomorphism over $ \mathbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I want to prove the following result :

> Let $X$ a finite-rank free $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module, and $\varphi \colon X \to X$ an endomorphism of $X$. Then $$|M/\varphi(X)| < \infty \Leftrightarrow v_p(\det \varphi) \neq 0$$and in the case where the cokernel is of finite , we
>   have that $|coker(\varphi)|=|X/\varphi(X)| = p^{v_p(\det \varphi)}$.

Can anyone help me to prove it, or give me a refernce  in which I can find a proof.

Thanks very much for any suggestion in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something but what is $M$? Also is that $\mathbb Z_p$ the finite field, or the $p$-adic one?

Comment: @DylanYott; sorry $M=X$ and $\mathbb Z_p$ the ring of p-adic integers.

Comment: do you mean $|\det\varphi|_p$?

Comment: @anon ; No, $v_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation $$|x|_p=(1/p)^{v_p(x)}$$.

Comment: Consider $\varphi=\rm Id$. Then $v_p(\det\varphi)=v_p(1)=0$ but $|X/\varphi(X)|=|X/X|=1<\infty$. I am pretty sure the claims should be about the $p$-adic absolute value of $\det\varphi$. Or actually, its reciprocal.

Comment: @anon ; I corrected the error;

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: as $\Bbb Z_p$ is a PID and $X$ is free, an endomorphism of $X$ can be written in [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).

Comment: Dear anon I'm not very familiar with Smith normal form. Can you explain a little more.

Comment: It would take awhile to explain SNF (plus I'm rusty and don't offhand remember the moves). My guess is that it's more or less essential though, so you should become familiar with it by reading around.

Comment: yes that's right, in any case thank you very much (+1).

Comment: anon I read SNF, but I do not see how I will use it to prove the result??

Comment: can you explain the usefulness of SNF ?

Comment: @Amine Did you figure out how to use SNF?

Comment: I read on SNF but I don't see how I can use it to prove the result

Comment: Do you know what $X/\varphi(X)$ is when $\varphi$ is given by a diagonal matrix?

Comment: no, but I think that is $X/det (\varphi)X$?

Comment: No. Let $X=R^n$ be the free module of rank $n$ over a commutative ring $R$. Suppose $$\varphi(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(a_1x_1,\cdots,a_nx_n)$$ is an $R$-module endomorphism of $R^n$. Then $$\varphi(R^n)=a_1R\oplus\cdots\oplus a_nR$$ and $$\frac{R\oplus\cdots\oplus R}{a_1R\oplus\cdots\oplus a_n R}\cong\frac{R}{a_1R}\oplus\cdots\oplus\frac{R}{a_nR}.$$ Are you starting to get any ideas?

Comment: if $$Mat(\varphi)=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0&0\\
                         0&\lambda_2&0\\
                          0&0&\lambda_2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ then we have $$X/\varphi X\cong \mathbb Z_p/(\lambda_1)\oplus\mathbb Z_p/(\lambda_2)\oplus\mathbb Z_p/(\lambda_3)$$right?

Comment: how we can find with this formula conditions on the cardinal of $X/\varphi X$ ?

Comment: anon. You can add some hint please, and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you figure out what the size of $\Bbb Z_p/(\lambda)$ is?

Comment: @Amine: Dear Amine, Based on your back-and-forth with anon, it seems that you would do well to follow his suggestion and consider the rank one case.  I.e. suppose that $X$ is just $\mathbb Z_p$ itself, so that $\varphi$ is just given as multiplication by some $p$-adic number $\lambda$.  If you can't solve your problem in this case, then you will need to relearn more basic facts about $\mathbb Z_p$.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE,thank you for the advice :).

Comment: anon, thank you so, so much for your help, I understand now.